# Installing tensorflow-GPU on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10

Since December, I am trying to install it and facing no result, I have to ask help...

So I tried many many things.

- I am under Windows 10  64.bit
- Python 3.6.3
- Anaconda3 5.0.1  pour windows x86_64
- Nvidia 970 GTX
- My current Nvidia CUDA version is 8.0 + Cudnn  ( by reading many posts is looked the working setup )

From there I do that in command prompt:

```
    -conda create -n tensorflow-gpu python=3.5.2      ( I have tried also 3.6.3 )
    -activate tensorflow-gpu
    -pip install tensorflow-gpu
    -activate tensorflow-gpu
    -Python
    -import tensorflow as tf
```

And the result is

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\tanit\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Any help is welcome